# WinCE MFC checking for SIM card existen?

Tags: windows-mobile, mfc

Is it possible to use WinCE MFC application to check if SIM card presents in device or not?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call SimInitialize and see if you get SIM_E_NOSIM.

Comment: I use SimInitialize but it returns S_OK all the times after I take out sim card.

Comment: Then check if you can read anything off the sim card using SimReadRecord or lineGetGeneralInfo.